# EF Core 2.0 Group By other properties

Tags: c#, group-by, entity-framework-core

I have 2 tables:

```
USERS
UserId
Name
Scores (collection of table Scores)

SCORES
UserId
CategoryId
Points
```

I need to show all the users and a SUM of their points, but also I need to show the name of the user. It can be filtered by CategoryId or not.

```
Context.Scores
.Where(p => p.CategoryId == categoryId) * OPTIONAL
.GroupBy(p => p.UserId)
.Select(p => new 
{
    UserId = p.Key,
    Points = p.Sum(s => s.Points),
    Name = p.Select(s => s.User.Name).FirstOrDefault()
}).OrderBy(p => p.Points).ToList();
```

The problem is that when I add the

```
Name = p.Select(s => s.User.Name).FirstOrDefault()
```

It takes so long. I don't know how to access the properties that are not inside the GroupBy or are a SUM. This example is very simple becaouse I don't have only the Name, but also other properties from User table.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It takes so long because the query is causing [client evaluation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval). See [Client evaluation performance issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval#client-evaluation-performance-issues) and how to use [Client evaluation logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval#client-evaluation-logging) to identify related issues.

If you are really on EF Core 2.0, there is nothing you can do than upgrading to v2.1 which contains improved [LINQ GroupBy translation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.1#linq-groupby-translation). Even with it the solution is not straight forward - the query still uses client evaluation. But it could be rewritten by separating the `GroupBy` part into subquery and joining it to the `Users` table to get the additional information needed.

Something like this:

```c#
var scores = db.Scores.AsQueryable();
// Optional
// scores = scores.Where(p => p.CategoryId == categoryId);

var points = scores
     .GroupBy(s => s.UserId)
     .Select(g => new
     {
         UserId = g.Key,
         Points = g.Sum(s => s.Points),
     });

var result = db.Users
    .Join(points, u => u.UserId, p => p.UserId, (u, p) => new
    {
        u.UserId,
        u.Name,
        p.Points
    })
    .OrderBy(p => p.Points)
    .ToList();
```

This still produces a warning

> The LINQ expression 'orderby [p].Points asc' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.

but at least the query is translated and executes as single SQL:

```sql
SELECT [t].[UserId], [t].[Points], [u].[UserId] AS [UserId0], [u].[Name]
FROM [Users] AS [u]
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT [s].[UserId], SUM([s].[Points]) AS [Points]
    FROM [Scores] AS [s]
    GROUP BY [s].[UserId]
) AS [t] ON [u].[UserId] = [t].[UserId]
```